# Cosine series with non-negative coefficients, that is continuous at $0$ but not everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, fourier-series

Is there an cosine series with non-negative terms, that is continuous at $x=0$, but not continuous everywhere?

More specifically, do there exist $a_n\geq0$ such that

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(nx) $$

- converges for $x=0$
- converges almost everywhere
- is continuous at $x=0$
- is not a continuous function?

For motiviation, see this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893025/is-there-a-positive-semidefinite-convolution-kernel-that-is-continuous-at-0-b).

Comment: If you take a bounded even function which is $2 \pi$-periodic, continuous at zero and disctontinuous somewhere else, then its Fourier series will converge to it almost everywhere, and will be made only by cosines.

Comment: But will we know its Fourier coefficients are $\geq0$? For the example of a symmetric step function, this is not the case.

Comment: By "is not a continuous function" you mean that there is no continuous function $g$ such that $f=g$ a.e.?

Comment: You cannot have the coefficients $a_n$ be summable(necessary for continuity at 0), positive and decreasing, at least. This would imply $n a_n \to 0$ and thus $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @CalvinKhor What about $a_n = 1/n$ ?

Comment: @amsmath that's not convergent at 0 (the harmonic series appears), contrary to assumptions in OP. I have edited my comment just in time to clarify this

Comment: I've recently learned that desmos implements summation, so if anyone else would like to explore with a graphing tool, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uuew6rewh8

Comment: Take the Fourier series of a periodic function with discontinuities.

Comment: Please take a look at Gibbs-Phenomenon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon

Comment: At least $(a_n)$ cannot be $\ell^1$ because in this case $f$ is a continuous function and the series converges everywhere. Hence, $f(0)$ is not defined (by the series).

Comment: OP, I suggest editing your post title and maybe also your post to point out the non-negativity assumption more clearly.

Comment: @amsmath thats what I said, pretty much. The non-negativity is the interesting part because there are examples like the squarewave in the above graph.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Which graph do you mean? And for my claim non-negativity is not needed. This is a simple consequence of Lebesgue's majorized convergence theorem.

Comment: @amsmath the desmos link above. I know the proof.

Comment: @CalvinKhor, thanks I will edit the title

Comment: @CalvinKhor In order to avoid misunderstandings, please don't change the meaning of your comments by editing. Thanks.

Comment: It still is not clarified what "continuous at zero" means if the function is not defined there.

Comment: @amsmath my apologies, you can think of the edit mark as an admission of error. I'm only allowed to edit the comments for 5 minutes, will you give me the same leeway as this website?

Comment: Yes, the original question required the function to be defined at zero. @amsmath I think you may have answered the question. Can you provide a link to the theorem that if $a_n$ are in $l^1$ then $f$ must be continuous?

Comment: This is simple. First, if $(a_n)\in\ell^1$, then the series obviously converges for every $x$. If $x_k\to x$, then $f(x_k)-f(x) = \sum_na_n(\cos(nx_k)-\cos(nx))$. Each summand converges to zero and is bounded by $2|a_n|$. Hence, Lebesgue's majorized convergence theorem implies that the whole thing tends to zero as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: @amsmath Thank you, I think that is the answer (in fact a stronger one): if the series converges at $x=0$, then $(a_n)\in l^1$, so $f(x)$ will be continuous everywhere. Could you post this as an answer, so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: @amsmath, Actually though I don't see how Lebesgues dominated convergence theorem is relevant - that is about limits of integrals, rather than showing continuity? But I can see an argument where you bound $|f(x')-f(x)| < \epsilon$ by finding $N$ where $2\sum_{n>N} a_n \leq \epsilon/2$, and $\delta$ where $|\sum_{n \leq N} a_n(\cos(nx')-\cos(nx))| \leq \epsilon/2$ if $|x'-x|<\delta$ by continuiity of a finite sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the series converges at $x=0$, then $\sum_na_n$ converges. And since $a_n\ge 0$, it follows that $(a_n)\in\ell^1$. But then the series converges at every $x$ and defines a continuous function $f$. To see the latter, let $(x_k)$ be a sequence in $\Bbb R$ that converges to $x\in\Bbb R$. Then
$$
f(x_k)-f(x) = \sum_na_n(\cos(nx_k)-\cos(nx)).
$$
Now, the $n$-th summand converges to zero as $k\to\infty$ is bounded by $2|a_n|$. Hence, by Lebesgue's majorized convergence theorem, it follows that $f(x_k)\to f(x)$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Marked as answered, but I still don't get how you used Lebesgues domainated convergence theorem here. (Assuming that's what you mean.) That theorem is about convergence of integrals, we are talking about convergence of limits.

Comment: @Neuromath The theorem is stated for integrals with respect to arbitrary measures. Here, it is the counting measure $\mu(A) = \#(A\cap\Bbb Z)$.

Answer (score 1):

For each $n,$ $|a_n\cos (nx)|\le a_n,$ and we're given $\sum a_n <\infty.$ By the Weierstrass M test, $\sum a_n\cos (nx)$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb R.$ Since each summand is continuous on $\mathbb R,$ so is $f(x).$ Thus the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is continous at $x=0$ then we know

$$ \exists L \land  \forall \epsilon \exists \delta \gt 0 \  \land   \ if \ |x| \lt \delta \ then \ |f(x)-L| \lt \epsilon$$

This immediately implies that there exists infinitly many  $x \neq 0$ such that $ |\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n cos(nx) - L| \lt \epsilon $.

Comment: I don't know how to find non continuous cases for $ a_n$ - part of your question. Just thought this might be helpful for other aspects of the question.

Comment: Also as some comented ask, not at no point do we consider when $x=0$ because our $\delta =0$ which is not found in definition of continuity.

Comment: Woops yes I redact last comment because it explicitly $f(x)=L$ to be cont at $x$.